# Android Cordova flaky on first load

Tags: android, cordova, telerik-appbuilder

I've built a Cordova 3.2.0 app using Telerik AppBuilder. Works perfectly on the simulator and on iOS.

Works fine on Android once it's "warmed up". However, I'm getting random issue from users on various devices with the toolbar not loading, only half the screen loading, app unresponsive etc.

Only happens on first load after a fresh install or update and is usually rectified by a reboot or two. Most recent recent report was 5 reboots to get it working smoothly!

My best guess is it's caching some of the HTML or Javascript assets and takes a few reboots to force the cache to clear? As I say, it works perfectly on iOS.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Rob